# JSON help needed - changing the height affects width

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

I am using JSON to format the Gallery (Tiles) view of my SharePoint Online list. For some reason, changing the height of a tile affects width too. How do I change the height only?

This is how the beginning of my JSON code looks like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
    "height": 700,
    "width": 254,
    ...
}
```

Edit: Added screenshots (had to blur out the confidential data sorry, but I think you can still see the difference).

The first image is:

```
"height": 700,
"width": 254,
```

The second image is:

```
"height": 600,
"width": 254,
```

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `fillHorizontally` property from JSON OR setting it to `false` like:

```
"fillHorizontally": false,
```

[image]

---

I just tested this on our SharePoint online list gallery view and changing the height of tile does not change the width of the tile.

Here are the results:

When height is equal to 200:

[image]

When height is equal to 350:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ganesh but it didn't work (neither setting the value to "false" nor deleting the property completely).

Comment: Can you add screenshots to your question to show us how the width is changing when height is changed?

Comment: I added the images, hopefully you can see the difference.
Also, changing the width value does nothing.

Comment: After removing `fillHorizontally`, try setting min-width and max-width properties to fixed value instead of just width property once.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to do this. I assume this is incorrect?

`  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 700,
  "width": 254,
  "min-width": "254px",
  "max-width": "254px",
  "hideSelection": false,`

Comment: You will have to use the min-width and max-width properties inside the `formatter` > `style` property. Check JSON given here for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-gallery-formatting#example-multi-line-custom-card

Comment: Thanks. This allowed me to change the width, but also affected the Tiles in an undesirable way. It aligned images right and text stopped wrapping. This is becoming too complicated, I think I will give up. Thank you Ganesh.

Comment: No problem. I am unable to reproduce your issue so can't help further as well. Width is not changing in my case (maybe because I am using content with less characters). I will have to do more tests with longer texts inside the tiles in gallery view.